auto_arima claims an error. Data investigation says it's not there
Bit of digging says I may have stumbled upon a known issue. https://github.com/alkaline-ml/pmdarima/issues/404. Has anyone ever found a solution?
I have a (nx1) dataset that I want to run a time series analysis on.
Here it is in dictionary form.
{'NUMBERS': {Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00'): 10213.532420631747, Timestamp('2022-02-01 00:00:00'): 10060.99736478822, Timestamp('2022-03-01 00:00:00'): 10114.340552694051, Timestamp('2022-04-01 00:00:00'): 9792.552184771394, Timestamp('2022-05-01 00:00:00'): 9842.465718515601, Timestamp('2022-06-01 00:00:00'): 9691.933576510868, Timestamp('2022-07-01 00:00:00'): 10249.764367820339, Timestamp('2022-08-01 00:00:00'): 9702.396869224209, Timestamp('2022-09-01 00:00:00'): 9931.576553673398, Timestamp('2022-10-01 00:00:00'): 10606.389793700864, Timestamp('2022-11-01 00:00:00'): 9944.065206790576, Timestamp('2022-12-01 00:00:00'): 9501.200623353445, Timestamp('2023-01-01 00:00:00'): 9920.810166892388, Timestamp('2023-02-01 00:00:00'): 9480.957659169962, Timestamp('2023-03-01 00:00:00'): 9219.515545883198, Timestamp('2023-04-01 00:00:00'): 9620.490220935744, Timestamp('2023-05-01 00:00:00'): 8837.298443135249, Timestamp('2023-06-01 00:00:00'): 8958.609717329557, Timestamp('2023-07-01 00:00:00'): 9146.214470367333, Timestamp('2023-08-01 00:00:00'): 9097.411947782966, Timestamp('2023-09-01 00:00:00'): 9500.538477492697, Timestamp('2023-10-01 00:00:00'): 9231.787966955351, Timestamp('2023-11-01 00:00:00'): 8953.040578652091, Timestamp('2023-12-01 00:00:00'): 9105.182195363403, Timestamp('2024-01-01 00:00:00'): 8674.445958062106, Timestamp('2024-02-01 00:00:00'): 8747.30162186934, Timestamp('2024-03-01 00:00:00'): 8855.463800560823, Timestamp('2024-04-01 00:00:00'): 8418.310475138638, Timestamp('2024-05-01 00:00:00'): 8307.04091206899, Timestamp('2024-06-01 00:00:00'): 8444.759943862811, Timestamp('2024-07-01 00:00:00'): 8091.653725481563}}

I'm trying a couple of different auto_arima configurations to get some predictions.
auto_arima(y = data3, m = 12, test = 'pp').predict(n_periods = 15)
auto_arima(y = data3, m = 1, test = 'pp').predict(n_periods = 15)

When I run either of them then I get this error.
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Yet when I check the dataframe python tell me that the dtype is float64, there are no nulls, and there are no infinities.
Here's the codethat does the check.
print(data3.info())
print('---')
print(data3.isnull().sum())
print('---')
print(data3.isin([np.inf, -np.inf]).sum())

And here's the results in this output.
DatetimeIndex: 31 entries, 2022-01-01 to 2024-07-01
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------   --------------  -----  
 0   NUMBERS  31 non-null     float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 496.0 bytes
None
---
NUMBERS    0
dtype: int64
---
NUMBERS    0
dtype: int64

What is going on?
How can the error be that the data is either NaN, infinity, or "too big for float64" when there are no nulls, there are no infinities, and the dtype of every element is float64?
